# Keycloak problems with Jakarta

Tags: keycloak, jakarta-migration

I have the problem that I can't use the library: keycloak-server-spi-private-20.0.2.jar because it still depends on Javax and not on Jakarta.

For the admin-client I found a Jakarta version but I can't find it for the server-spi.

Does somebody know if they changed up package structure or something with jakarta? I couldn't find any information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Will be resolved in Keycloak 22

https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/issues/16436

More details about in [Upgrade to Quarkus 3](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/issues/16246)